# Unicode White Heart Character Different Display in Win 7 from OS X 10.7.3

Tags: css, unicode

im using css to display unicode characters and i'm getting a different display in windows 7; in os x 10.7.3 it's a white heart: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/i/delete/white-heart-os-x-10.7.3-chrome-20.0.1096.1-dev.png   in win 7 its three lines http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/i/delete/white-heart-win-7-chrome-20.0.1105.2-dev-m.png  if it were the normal box for undisplayable chars, i wouldn't be so confused. is it my desktop? you can see the original page here: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/css/unicode/unicode-playing-card-block-css.html

Comment: what does the CSS actually look like?  Display of Unicode characters is dependant on font, so either your Unicode character is wrong in the CSS, or you are using the wrong font on Windows.

Comment: you can see it in the link; content:("/2661"); i don't see how it's the wrong font, the rest of the chars display correctly.

Comment: On the page you linked, the symbols are displayed two ways - the first table uses UTF-8 encoded character octets, and the second table uses CSS styles.  Both tables show all the symbols correctly in IE9 on my Windows 7, so it has to be a problem with your browser on Windows 7, it is not handling the CSS correctly.

Comment: Does this happen when you view the page you specify, or when you when your own page? In the latter case, provide the URL of your page and/or the code of a minimized version where the issue exists. What happens on your browsers when you view a page that simply contains the character ♡ as data?

Comment: @jukka sorry i don't understand what you mean. it happens on the page specified.

Comment: @albert, then the odds are that the font used for displaying the character (probably Cambria or Verdana) is broken in your computer. Check this out e.g. by using Character Map with the font set to Cambria (or, if not installed, Verdana) and looking for the character 2661.

Comment: @jukka i changed them to monospace...still doesn't work. i'm not sure if this helps, but i see the same three line character when i view this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols

Comment: @albert, what happened when you tested in Character Map? Such testing would help in isolating whether the problem is in a font or in a browser (it seems that you only tested on one browser).

Comment: @jukka what is character map? i did change the font to monospace...but i'm still getting the same results; dev tools confirms the font is monospace. i'll try character map if you think that's not good enough. i checked cross-browser/platform, to confirmed what i'm seeing. but here's the run down: in wind7 it renders in opera next 12, opera 11.62, ff 12, safari 5.5, ie9. it renders in os-x 10.7.3 chrome-20.0.1096.1-dev. it does not render in win7 chrome 20.0.1115.1 dev-m or canary 20.0.1119.0. screenshots: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/css/unicode/unicode-playing-card-block-css.html

Comment: @albert, Character Map is a standard utility program on Windows. This has got rather confused, so you should try to isolate the problem in the simplest possible setting. Test the fonts locally in Character Map first. Then, if the characters work OK there, construct a minimal web page, containing the characters as content (not as generated with CSS). If needed, post the URL of a simple test case. (The question looks like a candidate for closing as “too localized”, but it could be interesting to see what is really going on.) Oh, and setting font to monospace shouldn’t be expected to help.

Comment: @jukka i'll check out character map...the link has both characters and generated content in it. i can view the char, not the css. a vanilla sandbox is always helpful, i may do that next as well. i don't understand how it can be too localized, no one has responded that has viewed it (broken or not) in chrome on win7